# How to find String from multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find a string which I have in first column from another columns in the dateset. The dataset contains name in each column. Below is my dataset.

[image]

I am trying a following code but unable to find anything.

```
P_Name = new_data['P_Name_1']
for i in P_Name:
    new_data['new1'] = (new_data.iloc[:,1:].values == i).any(0)
new_data
```

f there is any similar name found( even first name or last name) it appears in the new column

Comment: `P_Name.str.find(string_to_search)` assuming you are using a `pandas` dataframe.

Comment: Its not working because I want to search Names which I have in P_Name series from other columns

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be aware that every iteration of your loop will overwrite the entry new_data['new1'].

Then the function x.any() will return a boolean value if any element in x equals to "True" or 1, so what your code would do is to assign a Boolean value to the column new_data['new1'].

I believe it would be easier for people to help if you can specify your problem more explicitly, for example, what's your desired output and what should the loop do?

Comment: I have added data sample and my output expectation, could you pls check now